# Conflict between arydshln and tabu and X column type?

Tags: tabu, arydshln

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabu}{l X}
a & b
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following two error messages over and over:

```
! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.10 \end{tabu}

I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.10 \end{tabu}

I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
or \cr or \span just now. If something like a right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.
```

If I do one of the following, the error disappears:

- Change the `X` column to `l`
- Remove `\usepackage{arydhsln}`

However, I have a big document that uses a lot of `tabu` `X` columns in some sections, and I need `arydshln` for the `\hdashline` command when drawing complex (not in the `sqrt(-1)` sense) mathematical matrices in other places.

Can this conflict be resolved? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to swap the loading order as `tabu` modifies some internals `arydshln` uses (as noted in section 9 of the documentation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabu}{l X}
a & b
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Swapping `arydshln` and `tabu` works when using the `article` class, but not when using `memoir`. Any ideas? Should I post a separate question?

Comment: @rudolfbyker Yes, you should, because memoir has completely different mechanics and implements many features right away (maybe even table features).