# Using arydshln, tabu and X columns with memoir

Tags: memoir, tabu, arydshln

This question is related to: [Conflict between arydshln and tabu and X column type?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425029/83295)

The following works with the article class, but not with memoir:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabu}{l X}
a & b
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If I change `article` to `memoir`, I get the following error repeatedly:

```
! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.10 \end{tabu}

I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.10 \end{tabu}

I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
or \cr or \span just now. If something like a right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.
```

I need both `\hdashline` from `arydshln` and `X` columns from `tabu` in my document.

Comment: just FYI: you get the same error using `article` if you load the `tabularx` package before `arydshln`.

Comment: @daleif Yes, that's what the linked question and answer is about.

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package: you can use both dashed lines and `X` columns with `memoir` class.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{l|[dashed]X}
  \hline
    a & b \\
  \hline[dashed]
    c & d \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer, even though it does not answer the question, in the hope that someone sees is and gets enough information to properly debug it.

This works, note `m` modifier for the `X`-column. I.e., you will perhaps not get the functionality you want, but it compiles.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabu}{l X[m]}
  a & b
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I just scripted the rest of the combinations (i.e. r, c, l or j (or R C L J) and p and b), only m works.

Comment: Bear in mind that `tabu` is buggy and not maintained package. Try to use some other package, for example `tabularx` with `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` redefined `X` column type.